# Global Variables in Scala

Tags: scala, dictionary, functional-programming

I'm new to Scala and functional programming for that matter. I'm trying to use the functionality of global variables inside my main() functions like this,

```
object Scala_Object {

  var myDict = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,String]()

  def str_rev(s : String) : String = {
    myDict.put(s,s.reverse)
    return (s.reverse)
  }

  def main (args: Array[String]){
    ..
    ..
    val result = parsedArray.map(line => line.map { word =>
      if( word == "") word 
      else if(word == line(2) || word == line(3)) str_rev(word)
      else if ( word == line(1) || word == line(26)) str_rev(word) 
      else word})      
}
```

At the end of my program only elements from my first line from parsedArray( which is an `Array[Array[String]]`) is added to the dict - myDict. Is there anything that I'm missing ? I noticed that there isn't doc/tutorial on Global variables, so I presume there is fundamentally No concept called Global variables in SCALA. Then, how is the concept of global variables handled in Scala ?

Comment: Please try to improve your code formatting next time :) It was kind of hard to read.

Comment: Your `myDict` is a global variable. It can be referenced by other classes as `Scala_Object.myDict`. And in a way `Scala_Object` is a global variable too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example should work fine. If there's a problem, it doesn't seem to be in the code you've posted. As a side note, your `myDict` does not need to be a `var` since you don't want to re-assign it. The `var` and `val` keywords in Scala refer not to the referenced object or class instance, but to the reference, for example:

```
val x = 5
x = 6 // This will fail, reassignment to val

var y = 3
y = 5 // This works

val z = mutable.Map[String,String]()
z.put("foo", "bar") // This works because the reference is not modified
z = mutable.Map[String,String]() // This fails
```

Here's how you test your `Scala_Object` on the Scala console:

```
scala> :paste
// Paste the code of your Scala_Object here
// And press Ctrl-D

defined module Scala_Object

scala> Scala_Object.myDict
res1: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,String] = Map()

scala> ScalaObject.str_rev("foo")
res4: String = oof

scala> ScalaObject.myDict
res5: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,String] = Map(foo -> oof)

scala> ScalaObject.str_rev("lol")
res6: String = lol

scala> ScalaObject.myDict
res7: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,String] = Map(lol -> lol, foo -> oof)
```